# Is there a simple way of finding the eigenstates of the creation and annihilation operator in QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space, eigenvalue

> How can I find the eigenstates of creation and annihilation operator in QM?

**My attempt**:

Such eigenstate will obey: $$ a^{\dagger} |\psi \rangle = \alpha |\psi \rangle. $$

We can expand $|\psi \rangle$ in terms of the quantum SHM eigenstates: $|\psi \rangle = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n |n\rangle $.

Knowing the action of the creation operation of quantum SHM eigenmodes ($a^{\dagger}|n\rangle = \sqrt{n+1}|n+1\rangle)$:

$$ a^{\dagger} |\psi \rangle = a^{\dagger} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n |n\rangle = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n \sqrt{n+1}|n+1\rangle$$

from which the state $|0\rangle$ is now missing, so it will never be equal to the RHS of the first expression, $\alpha |\psi\rangle = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \alpha c_n |n\rangle $.

Comment: The creation operator cannot possibly have eigenstates. The eigenstates of the annihilation operator are called "coherent states". Google it :)

Comment: This is no surprise, as $a$ and $a^\dagger$ are not self-adjoint

Comment: …but see [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/532006/66086)…

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Write an arbitrary state as

$$|\Psi\rangle = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n |n\rangle \,.$$

Now apply the raising operator

$$
\begin{align}
a^\dagger |\Psi\rangle &=
a^\dagger \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n |n\rangle \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n \sqrt{n+1} |n+1\rangle \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{n-1} \sqrt{n} |n\rangle
\end{align}
$$

If $|\Psi\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $a^\dagger$ with eigenvalue $\alpha$ then we have

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n|n\rangle = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_{n-1} \sqrt{n}|n \rangle \, .$$

You already got this far.
Indeed, the only solution to this equation is $c_n=0$ for all $n$.
Therefore, there is no eigenstate of $a^\dagger$.

The eigenstates of $a$, which are called "coherent states" are given by

$$
|\alpha \rangle = e^{-|\alpha|^2/2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}}|n\rangle \, .
$$
You can check easily by applying $a$ to $|\alpha \rangle$ that $|\alpha \rangle$ is an eigenstate of $a$.

Comment: Can you please explain why $c_{n}$ =0 for all n, is the only solution for creation operator case

Comment: @SSP_user5275 The right hand side of the equation has no $|0\rangle$ term, so the left hand side must also have no $|0\rangle$ term, and so $c_0=0$. Now consider the $|1\rangle$ term and we get $c_1 = c_0 \sqrt{1} = 0$. Repeat this argument for all terms.

Comment: Did you miss a factor of $\alpha$ on the LHS below "If |Ψ⟩
 is an eigenstate of †
 with eigenvalue 
 then we have"? It doesn't change the conclusion I think, it's just that one must treat $\alpha \neq 0$ and $\alpha = 0$.

Comment: Notice that the starting index of the sum is 1 not 0.