# Eigenstates of sum of creation and annihilation operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space, harmonic-oscillator

Does the operator $a+a^\dagger$ have eigenstates? If yes, what are they?

Comment: No, it has not discrete spectrum on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$. In fact it is proportional to the position operator (or the momentum one, depends on you definition) and those have purely continuous spectrum, so no eigenstates that are square integrable.

Comment: Closely related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/155852/80818

Comment: @yuggib: Once again, that's an answer ;)

Comment: $\hat x =\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2 m \omega}} (a+a^\dagger)$, thus up to scaling - this operator has the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the position operator

Comment: @Alexander Either you or yuggib should make your comments into answers!

Answer (score 4):

No, it has not discrete spectrum (on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$). In fact $a+a^*$ is proportional to the position operator (or the momentum one, depends on your definition of $a$ and $a^*$; by the usual one the position operator $x$ is proportional to the real part $a+a^*$ and the momentum $p$ to the imaginary part $\frac{1}{i}(a-a^*)$). Both position and momentum operators have purely continuous spectrum, so there are no eigenstates that are square integrable (but there are the usual "generalized eigenvectors"; i.e. delta functions for the position operator).

Comment: In my QM mechanics class, that would be translated into: write down $|x\rangle$ and don't ask any questions!

Comment: @jinawee good ol' physics style :-P

Comment: @jinawee There [are](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/445144/eigenstates-of-the-creation-operator?noredirect=1&lq=1) places where questions are answered: Dirac's QM book.