# Is it possible to build eigenstates of linear combinations of $\hat{P}$ and $\hat{X}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, harmonic-oscillator, mathematics, eigenvalue

For the quantum harmonic oscillator, the position operator $\hat{X}$ has eigenstates saisfying $\hat{X}|x\rangle = x | x \rangle$. The momentum operator meanwhile acts like $\langle x | \hat{P} | \Psi \rangle = - i \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \langle x | \Psi \rangle$ in this eigenbasis.

My question is if we define some operator $\hat{O} = \hat{X} + \lambda \hat{P}$ (with $\lambda$ some dimensionful quantity), if it is possible to define eigenstates of $\hat{O}$? Something like $\hat{O} | o \rangle = o | o \rangle$ with $o$ built out of $x$ and $p$ eigenvalues possibly.

My guess is that you cannot do this, but I would like to understand this better.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Is it important that it is an eigenstate of $P + X$? What about the QHO, i.e. $\sim X^2+P^2$? Or perhaps. $S_x+S_y$? In general yes, you can "build" eigenstates of non-commuting self-adjoint operators. However, for the case asked here there might be some subtleties regarding the domain(s) etc. In any case, have you tried to solve the corresponding formal differential equation?

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/445144/eigenstates-of-the-creation-operator/532006#532006).

Answer (score 3):

The position operator of a free particle in the Heisenberg picture is a nice example ($\hbar=1$): $$X(t)= e^{iP^2 t/2m} X e^{-i P^2 t/2m} = X+ Pt/m$$ The eigenstates of $X(t)$ are given by $|x;t \rangle := e^{iP^2 t/2m} |x\rangle$, as $$(X+Pt/m) |x;t \rangle = X(t) e^{iP^2 t/2m}| x \rangle = e^{iP^2 t/2m} X | x \rangle = x  e^{iP^2/2m} |x \rangle = x |x; t\rangle.$$ As $X$ and $X+Pt/m$ are unitarily equivalent, the spectra of $X$ a and $X+Pt/m$ are, of course, identical (namely $\mathbb{R}$).

This delivers at the same time the general solution of your question for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Replacing $t/m$ by  the parameter $\lambda$, the unitary operator $U(\lambda):= e^{-iP^2 \lambda /2}$ maps the operator $X$ into $X+\lambda P$  via $U^\dagger(\lambda) X U(\lambda) = X+ \lambda P$ with eigenstates (better: eigendistributions) $|x; \lambda \rangle = U^\dagger(\lambda) |x\rangle$, i.e. $(X+\lambda P) |x;\lambda \rangle = x |x; \lambda \rangle$.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is if we define some operator $\hat{O} = \hat{X} + \lambda \hat{P}$ (with $\lambda$ some dimensionful quantity), if it is possible to define eigenstates of $\hat{O}$? Something like $\hat{O} | o \rangle = o | o \rangle$ with $o$ built out of $x$ and $p$ eigenvalues possibly.

Yes, it is possible.

For example (with $\hbar=1$):
$$
\psi(x) = Ae^{\frac{i}{2\lambda}(x - x_0)^2}\;,
$$
satisfies:
$$
\left(\hat X + \lambda \hat P\right) \psi = x_0 \psi
$$

---

A typical example of when such a linear combination of $\hat X$ and $\hat P$ occurs is in the usual "ladder" analysis of the simple harmonic oscillator, where lowering and raising operators are typically presented as:
$$
a \propto \hat X + \frac{i}{m\omega}\hat P
$$
$$
a^\dagger \propto \hat X - \frac{i}{m\omega}\hat P\;,
$$
respectively.

Eigenstates of the lowering operator are called "coherent states."

Comment: But it is not an element of $L^2$...

Comment: @Tobias the OP did not stipulate real λ.

Comment: Okay, I agree... For some reason I had $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ in mind, such that we deal with a hermitian operator.

Comment: it's but the Fock vacuum in coordinate space....