# QM: Why does the creation operator not have eigenstates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space

I know that coherent states are the eigenstates of the annihilation operator and i assumed that 
$a^{+} |n \rangle =\sqrt{n+1}|n+1\rangle$ was the creation operators eigenstate, why is this not an eigenstate?

Comment: Because $\sqrt{n+1}|n+1\rangle$ is not of the form $(\text{constant})|n\rangle$. An eigenstate satisfies $(\text{Operator})|\text{eigenstate}\rangle=(\text{constant})|\text{eigenstate}\rangle$. Also, $a^\dagger$ is the creation operator, not the annihilation operator.

Comment: @JahanClaes: That should be an answer.

Comment: See also [https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/155852/is-there-a-simple-way-of-finding-the-eigenstates-of-the-creation-and-annihilatio](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/155852/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given an operator $A$, an eigenstate of such operator with eigenvalue $a$ is a vector $|a\rangle$ such that the application of the original operator onto the mentioned vector gives back the same vector multiplied by a factor $a$, namely $A|a\rangle = a|a\rangle$.

In your example 
$$
a^{\dagger}|n\rangle = \sqrt{n+1}|n+1\rangle
$$
you can see that the state on the right hand side is not the same state on the left hand side.

Comment: Downvoted...why?

Comment: I agree with the above comment. This is the right answer. It should not be downvoted.

Comment: This is not the answer as to why the raising ladder operator has no eigenvalues, nor eigenvectors.

Comment: The question in the text is why the n+1 state is not an eigenstate, so it seems as there are two different questions here.

Comment: The question is two questions, but one of them is a duplicate of a question that already has answers. This answers the question that isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @DanielC As far as I understand, that isn't what the question is asking, or am I wrong?