# Is this an eigenfunction of a ladder operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator, eigenvalue

$a^{\dagger}$ and $a$ are ladder operators:

$a^{\dagger}|n\rangle = \sqrt{n+1}|n+1\rangle  \,\,\text{and}\,\,  a|n\rangle= \sqrt{n}|n-1\rangle $

Is the state $|n\rangle$ an eigenfunction of $a\dagger$ ?

Comment: Do you know what the definition of "eigenfunction" or "eigenstate" is?

Comment: If you know what it is then the answer should fall right out

Comment: @AaronStevens okay but I'm not confident in my answer

Comment: @medifleecenavidad Please learn "Mathjax"(a formalism close to Latex) in order write mathematical formulas.

Comment: @FredericThomas As much as I would like to, I do not have the time to do so. I'm doing as much as I can in my limited amount of time, I came here for help, not to be criticsed. I am not a Mathematics nor a Physics student. If you can understand what I am trying to get across, then that is all that matters. Have a good day.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/155852/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/483181/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic I thank you highly for this, I am very appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

An eigenstate of an operator is a state that is rescaled when the operator acts on it. $|n+1\rangle$ is not parallel to $|n\rangle$.